# What is the story of Ashokasundari, third child of Lord Shiva and Parvati?

Tags: shiva, parvati

Kartikeya and Ganesh are two commonly known sons of Lord Shiva and Parvati, but very few know that they had three kids. When and how did that third child Ashokasundari born? What is the full story related to the third child of Lord Shiva and Parvati?

Comment: there r many: Andhaka, Sukesha, Ashokasundari, Ayyapa, Hanumana..etc....which one u r referring here?..

Comment: @YDS   Ashokasundari

Comment: @lse I have edited your Q based on your last comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till date even I was believing that Shiva & Parvati have two sons, namely Kartikeya & Ganesha, but, I read on internet that Shiva & Parvati have three children – Kartikeya, Ganesha, & Ashoksundari – a less known daughter of Shiva & Parvati. Moreover, she is the middle child of ShivaShakti and was born before Lord Ganesha. Like Ganesha was born out of the waste of the body of Parvati, Ashoksundari was born out of Kalpavariksha – a wish-fulfilling tree. When Parvati was sad due to the separation pangs of her husband Shiva and beloved son Kartikeya, she wished for another child from the Kalpavariksha, when the divine tree granted her wish, Ashokasundari born thus. The irony is, only a few knowledgeable people are aware of the third child of Shiva & Parvati, but she is duly worshipped in South India as MaaBalaSundari.